# Find non-static [value] and paste range (F1:G1) next to "found" cell - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of query words that I am submitting to a database (Column A) to generate a list of coded matches (Columns F-H). Column F is the original search word (so there is an exact match somewhere in Column A), Column G contains the match, and Column H contains the code for the match. What I need to do is take the query word in Column F and find its partner in Column A. Then I need to take the corresponding match and its code and paste it next to the original search term in Column A (in Columns B&C).

My problem here is getting the information pasted in the correct cell since the copy to and paste from locations change every time -- The list of coded matches in Columns F-H does NOT contain all of the terms in Column A.

I've been searching the internet and I can't seem to figure out what exactly I need to change to allow the paste function to work.

I have attached an image of a simplified version of my spreadsheet and a annotated version of the code I have been working with.

```
Sub FindMatch()

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    FindMe = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Set FoundinList = Cells.Find(What:=FindMe, After:=ActiveCell, LookAt:=xlWhole) 

    If Not FoundinList Is Nothing Then
        FoundinList.Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

'At this point the cell I want the information pasted into is selected. Yay! 
'Example: I am trying to find "abnormal digits" (F1) in Column A and paste 
'G1:H1 into the appropriate cells in Columns B & C (In this case B15:C15) 
'At this point in the code my cursor is on cell B15 - which is where I need it.

        Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 8)).Copy

'This selects the appropriate range (G1:H1 in my example).

        ActiveCell.Paste

'This is the problem string. I've tried naming the "ActiveCell" before initiating the copy 
'string (ActiveCell.Name = "PasteHere") and then pasting into the named cell 
'(Cells("PasteHere").Paste), but that gives me an invalid procedure call or argument on: 
'Cells("PasteHere").Paste    I've also tried pasting into a range:Range(Cells(PasteHere, 2)
', Cells(PasteHere, 3)).Paste -AND- using the formula that is created when you a record a 
'macro (Application.CutCopyMode = False) but both of those give me an application
'/object-defined error. 

    End If
Next i
End sub
```

Thank you so much in advance for reading this post and helping me out.

[My Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H09df.png)

[End Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j92C.png)

Comment: Can you not use a simple vlookup formula in b and c?

Comment: I think a vlookup (or index/match) formula would work.  Do you mind posting an example of what it should look like in the end?

Comment: I am new to VBA, so I am not sure if vlookup would work. I can definitely look into that though!

Comment: @ahhn VLookup isn't a VBA method - it's a worksheet function. [Have a look at this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: I'm not sure then if vlookup would work if it can't be used in VBA. I have over 2,500 entries in Column A which is why I was looking for a macro to help me to re-organize the output from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This vba uses the worksheet function vlookup.

```
Sub ahhn()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    For Each cel In .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        cel.Offset(0, 1) = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cel, .Range("F:H"), 2, 0), "")
        cel.Offset(0, 2) = WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.VLookup(cel, .Range("F:H"), 3, 0), "")
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you!
Do you mind explaining to me what it is doing?